# Android, Add an extended view to xml layout

Tags: android

i'm following this tut 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

and i was wondering how can i add the customView to the main.xml layout

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_title" />

    <com.package.profile.view.HelloListView 
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

the HelloListView class package is com.package.profile.view

i get error
01-30 16:00:38.875: E/AndroidRuntime(27614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.profile/com.package.profile.ListDemoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Class is not a View com.package.profile.view.HelloListView

Thanks.

Comment: Please share you code for "HelloListView.java" seems it is not extending from ListView or View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't extend a `View`, but an `Activity`, more precisely a `ListActivity`. Your main layout should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_title" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```